# Calling another page using DataTable - Instant Row Selection

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `dataTable` but when I select a row nothing happens, I've tried calling `p:dialog` and nothing happened. I tried to redirect to another page with the selected data and also could not (this is my goal). What is missing in my code do. Below is my xhtml and bean.

xhtm:

```
<h:form id="form" style="font-size: 11pt">
<h3>Cancelar Processo de Portabilidade</h3>

<p:panel header="Consulta por Numeração" id="CancProcP1">


<h:panelGrid columns="3" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5"
    id="pgridTipoCanc1">

    <p:selectOneRadio id="tipoCancela"
        value="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="TN" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bilhete" itemValue="2" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Período" itemValue="3" />
        <f:ajax render="pgridTipoCanc2" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5"
    id="pgridTipoCanc2">

    <h:outputLabel for="tn" value="TN:"
        rendered="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca == '1'}" />
    <h:inputText id="tn" value="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tn}"
        rendered="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca == '1'}" />

    <h:outputLabel for="bilhete" value="Bilhete de Portabilidade:"
        rendered="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca == '2'}" />
    <h:inputText id="bilhete"
        value="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.srvProvId}"
        rendered="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca == '2'}" />

    <h:outputLabel for="dataInicial" value="Data Inicial"
        rendered="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca == '3'}" />
    <p:calendar id="dataInicial"
        value="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.dataInicial}"
        rendered="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca == '3'}" />

    <h:outputLabel for="dataFinal" value="Data Final"
        rendered="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca == '3'}" />
    <p:calendar id="dataFinal"
        value="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.dataFinal}"
        rendered="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.tipoBusca == '3'}" />

</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton id="pesquisar"
    action="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.pesquisar}"
    value="Buscar" ajax="false" update="display" />

</p:panel>
</h:form>

<p:panel id="CancProcP2">

<h:form id="form2" style="font-size: 11pt">

<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>                 

<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="valor"
    value="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.listaNumeroPortado}" 
    paginator="true" rows="5" rowKey="#{valor.srvProvIdDoadoraAnterior}" 
    selection="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.selectedNumP}" selectionMode="single"
    rowSelectListener="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.onRowSelect}"
    onRowSelectUpdate="display growl"
    onRowSelectComplete="carDialog.show()"
    rowUnselectListener="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.onRowUnselect}"  
    onRowUnselectUpdate="growl"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="4,5,7"
    style="max-width: 580px; min-width: 550px">
    <f:facet name="header"> 

</f:facet>

<p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />  

<p:column
        style="max-width: 50px; min-width: 50px; overflow: hidden">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Operadora Doadora" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{valor.srvProvIdDoadoraAnterior}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column
        style="max-width: 40px; min-width: 40px; overflow: hidden">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Bilhete" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{valor.srvProvId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column
        style="max-width: 40px; min-width: 40px; overflow: hidden">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Data/Hora da Janela" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{valor.dataJanelaPortabilidade}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column
        style="max-width: 40px; min-width: 40px; overflow: hidden">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Telefone" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{valor.tn}" />
    </p:column>



</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"  
width="200" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">

    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

        <f:facet name="header">  
        <p:graphicImage value="teste"/>  
        </f:facet>  

        <h:outputText value="Model:" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.selectedNumP.srvProvIdDoadoraAnterior}" /> 

    </h:panelGrid>

</p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

Bean

```
public class BuscarDadosCancelarPortBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<NumeroPortado> regSelecionado = null;

    private String tipoBusca;
    private String tn;
    private String srvProvId;
    private Date dataInicial;
    private Date dataFinal;

    private List<NumeroPortado> listaNumeroPortado = null;
    NumeroPortado numPortato = new NumeroPortado(); 

    private NumPortadoDataModel numModel;

    private NumeroPortado selectedNumP; 


    @EJB
    private ConsultasSpnService consultaOp;

    public List<NumeroPortado> pesquisar(){

        String busca = null;
        //String busca = "tn";
        //String parametro = "1133100038";
        String parametro = null;
        String parametro2 = null;

        if(tipoBusca.equals("1")){

            parametro = tn;
            busca = "tn";

        }else if(tipoBusca.equals("2")){

            parametro = srvProvId;//bilhete
            busca = "bilhete";

        }else if(tipoBusca.equals("3")){

            //DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy"); 

            //parametro = df.format(dataInicial);
            //parametro2 = df.format(dataFinal);
            //busca = "data";

        }       

        if(listaNumeroPortado == null){
            listaNumeroPortado = new ArrayList<NumeroPortado>();
            listaNumeroPortado = consultaOp.listarNumerosPortados(busca, parametro, parametro2);

            //Excluir depois de descobrir porque não está pegando estes campos da tabela
            for(int i=0;i<listaNumeroPortado.size();i++){

                if(tipoBusca.equals("1")){
                    listaNumeroPortado.get(i).setTn(parametro);
                }else if(tipoBusca.equals("2")){
                    listaNumeroPortado.get(i).setSrvProvId(parametro);
                }


            }
            //numModel = new NumPortadoDataModel(listaNumeroPortado);



        }   


        return listaNumeroPortado;



    }

    public String getTn() {
        return tn;
    }
    public void setTn(String tn) {
        this.tn = tn;
    }
    public String getSrvProvId() {
        return srvProvId;
    }
    public void setSrvProvId(String srvProvId) {
        this.srvProvId = srvProvId;
    }
    public Date getDataInicial() {
        return dataInicial;
    }
    public void setDataInicial(Date dataInicial) {
        this.dataInicial = dataInicial;
    }
    public Date getDataFinal() {
        return dataFinal;
    }
    public void setDataFinal(Date dataFinal) {
        this.dataFinal = dataFinal;
    }

    public String getTipoBusca() {
        return tipoBusca;
    }

    public void setTipoBusca(String tipoBusca) {
        this.tipoBusca = tipoBusca;
    }

    public List<NumeroPortado> getListaNumeroPortado() {
        return listaNumeroPortado;
    }

    public void setListaNumeroPortado(List<NumeroPortado> listaNumeroPortado) {
        this.listaNumeroPortado = listaNumeroPortado;
    }

    public NumeroPortado getNumPortato() {
        return numPortato;
    }

    public void setNumPortato(NumeroPortado numPortato) {
        this.numPortato = numPortato;
    }

    public ConsultasSpnService getConsultaOp() {
        return consultaOp;
    }

    public void setConsultaOp(ConsultasSpnService consultaOp) {
        this.consultaOp = consultaOp;
    }

    public List<NumeroPortado> getRegSelecionado() {
        return regSelecionado;
    }

    public void setRegSelecionado(List<NumeroPortado> regSelecionado) {
        this.regSelecionado = regSelecionado;
    }

    public NumPortadoDataModel getNumModel() {
        return numModel;
    }

    public void setNumModel(NumPortadoDataModel numModel) {
        this.numModel = numModel;
    }

    public NumeroPortado getSelectedNumP() {
        return selectedNumP;
    }

    public void setSelectedNumP(NumeroPortado selectedNumP) {
        this.selectedNumP = selectedNumP;
    } 

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Line Selected", ((NumeroPortado) event.getObject()).getTn());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  

    public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Line Unselected", ((NumeroPortado) event.getObject()).getTn());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  

    public String onRowSelectNavigate(SelectEvent event) {  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("selectedNumP", event.getObject());  

        return "cancelarPortabilidade?faces-redirect=true";  
    }

}
```

I changed the `rowSelectListener = "#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.onRowSelect}"` by `rowSelectListener = "#{beanBuscarDadosCancPort.onRowSelectNavigate}"` without success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got using only the tag 
`<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="# {beanConsultaPorNum.onRowSelectHeader}" />` between `<p:dataTable...> </p:dataTable>.`